# Three SPST switches, two LEDs, implementing two logic functions

Tags: circuit-design

Given an appropriate power supply, two LEDs, current-limiting resistors, and three SPST switches, build a circuit such that:

- When switches A and B are closed, LED 1 is on (otherwise off), and
- When switches B or C are closed, LED 2 is on (otherwise off).

It may not be possible to construct this circuit without using additional current-blocking diodes.

If there is an analytical solution available—i.e. mathematical evidence that the requested circuit is either possible or impossible to build given those parts—I'd be very interested to see that, as well.

Context: I gave the challenge to students in an off-the-cuff fashion, not realizing that actually the problem may have been intractable. (Don't worry—it's for a draft recording that hasn't been released to them yet.) Once I was finding that I couldn't quickly solve the problem I myself had posed, I became surprised at some of the subtleties it had exposed.

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 7mj445qgh93j]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you solve either sub-case individually?

Comment: What kind of switches are they? SPST? Can you use SPDT or DPDT? Is the power supply assumed to be able to drive LEDs without resistors so that the LEDs don't burn up? Or do the LEDs have built-in resistors? This has got to be an assignment as it is a non-pratical LED circuit, maybe it used lamps before the wording was converted to use more modern LEDs.

Comment: Hint: switch B is common.

Comment: what about A, B and C closed?

Comment: I am not sure why you write comments and replies in your question.

Comment: Second circuit - move switch C to a similar position to switch A. You do realise you’ve failed your boolean logic class......

Comment: @RobertZacharias Please don't use questions to reply, use the comments for that. Also if you edit the question you can draw circuit lab circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with SPST switches only, you must use diodes to isolate the current path or some another approach.

[image]

Comment: You could also use DPST (or DPDT) switches

Comment: I imagine there's some sneaky way of wiring it so that you use the LEDs as the current blocking diodes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Closing B would light LED2, which makes this invalid, unfortunately. As per Alan Birtles's comment, I was hoping there was some way to use the LEDs themselves to achieve the blocking needed, so that the only components are the switches and LEDs (and resistors). Also, it seems D4 isn't necessary, no?

Comment: I see an OR in second condition (B or C) in you question so B itself should makes Led2 on, no? D4 is not necessary, it is there just for current equality (make constant Led2 brightness).

Comment: I apologize @MichalPodmanicky—you're absolutely right. B alone should light LED2, and therefore this solution is valid. Thanks for posting it. As I said before, I'd love to see a solution with only switches and LEDs, as per @AlanBirtles 's suggestion, but I don't know if that's possible.